# Conditional comment for outlook desktop version not working

Tags: outlook, html-email, email-client

I keep encountering problems with my conditional comments for outlook desktop version. When viewing the email in outlook 2013 it is still showing it with border and the same font-size as for non-mso clients.

I also put the conditional comments in the head tag, but it did not work either.

If any of you can spot a typo or error somewhere in the code?

Thats the entire code I am using:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <title>Outlook conditional comments</title>

    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">

</head>

    <body>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <table class="lookout" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="max-width: 600px; 
    width: 100%; height: auto; font-size:3em;"> <tbody> <tr> <td>Increasing sales </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
    <![endif]-->
        <table class="lookout" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%; height: auto; font-size:1em;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Increasing Sales</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance
Danie

Answer (score 1):

It is showing the border because the second `<table>` is not hidden from Outlook. Outlook 2007/10/13/16 displays both `<table>`s.

We want to write two tables and wrap each in an `<mso>` tag: one that *displays* a `<table>` only for Outlook 2007/10/13/16, and one that *hides* a `<table>` only for Outlook 2007/10/13/16. Something like this:

```
<body>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <table class="lookout" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="max-width: 600px; 
    width: 100%; height: auto; font-size:3em;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Increasing sales In Outlook 2007/10/13/16</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
    <table class="lookout" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%; height: auto; font-size:1em;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Increasing Sales everywhere else</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

It shows with a Border and font-size bacause the Bottom Table isn't hidden. Also I most times use this Term: `<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>` It seems to work the best for most MSO Clients

Answer (score 0):

@Niklas and @Ted: many thanks for your replies.

I did another attempt and sent the email exactly the way you suggested Ted, but unfortunately the border and 1em font-size were there again in Outlook 2013. 
I was wonder whether the email client it is sent from can have an impact on how it is displayed in the email client it is viewed later on. I sent it from gmail. I saved the html doc from the browser and copied it over to gmail.

This is how the html file I copied looks like:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <title>Outlook conditional comments</title>

    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">

</head>

    <body>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <table class="lookout" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%; height: auto; font-size:3em;"> <tbody> <tr> <td>Increasing sales 13</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if !mso 9]>      <!-->
        <table class="lookout" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%; height: auto; font-size:1em;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Increasing Sales everwhere else</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     <!--<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts or comment on the new code are highly appreciated.

Danie